# TListView: on item added?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-7, tlistview

How can I catch the event when an item is added to TListView?

I thought the `OnInsert` event would do the job, according to the documentation.  It even passes the actual `TListItem` object to the handler:

> **OnInsert** Occurs immediately after a new item is inserted into the list
>   view.
>
> Write an OnInsert event handler to respond when an item has just been
>   added to the list. **The Item parameter is the TListItem object that was
>   added to the Items property**

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ListView1.Items.Add do
  begin
     Caption := 'foo';
     SubItems.Add('bar');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TListView1Insert(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
   //Item is empty
   ShowMessage(Item.Caption);
end;
```

But surprisingly, the `Item.Caption` is always empty. Seems nonsense to me.

**EDIT:**

Switching to `Items.AddItem()`, as suggested, leads to another weird issue. 
The `OnInsert` event handler now works as expected, however `TListView` does not display the `TListItem.Caption`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ListView1.Items.Add do
  begin
     Caption := 'foo1';
     SubItems.Add('bar1');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TListItem;
begin
  item := TListItem.Create(ListView1.Items);
  item.Caption := 'foo2';
  item.Subitems.Add('bar2');
  ListView1.Items.AddItem(item);
end; 

procedure TForm1.ListView1Insert(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  //this now works as expected
  ShowMessage(Item.Caption);
end;
```

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: It should be ListView1 and not TListView1. Also use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate procedures when you add items.

Comment: Note that calling `(Begin|End)Update()` only affects the ListView's painting (to avoid repaints while you are making changes to items), not its events

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes sure! I suggested to use them because I always do that when I deal with items to be edited (in particular if they are a lot). I guess that they should be used in any case

Comment: This is odd. Aren't you in control of adding items

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure if that's the best way, but I'm adding the items to ListView from within another thread. When an item is added that meets certain criteria I want to execute some action in the main thread.

Comment: You can't add items in another thread. VCL access needs to be in main thread. Whatever you are trying to do, GUI control events are the wrong solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We are not allowed to populate VCL controls from another thread? So this example, is then just wrong? https://www.thoughtco.com/multithreaded-delphi-database-queries-1058158

Comment: Correct. Utter bunk. I'm afraid that an overwhelming majority of what Zarko writes is flawed. I would trust nothing that you read of his. Anyway, I feel very strongly that the entire premise of the question is wrong. You are only wishing to respond to an event because you are adding the items in the wrong place. If you moved the code that worked with the VCL into the main thread (you have to do this), you wouldn't need to respond to an event. You could perform the action at the same time as you add the item.

Comment: Here's the rub. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TListView.OnInsert` event is indeed triggered when a new item is added to the ListView.  However, the `Item` is added to the ListView when `TListView.Items.Add()` is called, not when `Button1Click()` exits.  The `OnInsert` event handler is called (in response to a [`LVN_INSERTITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774841.aspx) notification) while `Add()` is still running.  So, of course the `Item` in the `OnInsert` event handler will always be empty, as you haven't assigned any values to it yet.

---

**Update**: When a `TListItem` is added to the ListView, the `LVIF_TEXT` flag of the underlying [`LVITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) is not enabled.  To display the `TListItem.Caption` and `TListItem.SubItems` text, `TListView` is designed to rely on [`ListView_SetItemText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775105.aspx) with the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` flag instead:

> This parameter can be LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK to indicate a callback item for which the parent window stores the text. In this case, the list-view control sends the parent an `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification code when it needs the text.

If you assign the `TListItem.Caption` or `TListItem.SubItems` property while the `TListItem` is not actually in the ListView yet, the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` flag will not get applied to those fields.  `LVN_GETDISPINFO` will not query the `TListView` for the text of the 1st column without `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` (as column 0 has special meaning at the OS layer), but it does query for the text of the 2nd column (even if `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` is not applied to it).  That is why your second example is missing the `'foo2'` caption text in the UI, but not the `'bar2'` text.

The actual `'foo2'` caption string is stored in the `TListItem` object, which is why your `ShowMessage()` is able to work.

So, if you create a new `TListItem` and modify its `Caption` before the item has been added to the ListView, you will have to call `ListView_SetItemText()` manually to enable the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` flag for the caption, eg:

```
uses
  Commctrl;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TListItem;
begin
  item := TListItem.Create(ListView1.Items);
  item.Caption := 'foo2';
  item.Subitems.Add('bar2');
  ListView1.Items.AddItem(item);
  ListView_SetItemText(ListView1.Handle, item.Index, 0, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK);
end;
```

Or, reset the `Caption` property value temporarily (the property setter checks for a duplicate string before calling `ListView_SetItemText()`):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TListItem;
begin
  item := TListItem.Create(ListView1.Items);
  item.Caption := 'foo2';
  item.Subitems.Add('bar2');
  ListView1.Items.AddItem(item);
  item.Caption := '';
  item.Caption := 'foo2';
end;
```

Just note that either way, the `TListItem.Caption` text will not appear in the UI until after the `OnInsert` event is called first, since it is triggered while `AddItem()` is running.

I reproduced this in XE2.  If the problem still happens in 10.2 Tokyo, I would suggest [filing a bug report](http://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.  `AddItem()` should probably be forcing `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` after insertion for any already-assigned string fields, or at least the `Caption`, anyway.

Comment: What should I do to access the newly added item's values then?

Comment: Setup an item and use AddItem.

Comment: DONT use `ListView.Items.Add()` to create a new `TListItem` that will be passed to `TListView.Items.AddItem()`.  Use `TListItem.Create(ListView.Items)` instead.  Or better: `TListViewAccess(ListView).CreateListItem()` (where `TListViewAccess` is `type TListViewAccess = class(TListView) end;`, as `CreateListItem()` is declared as `protected`). Using `CreateListItem()` allows users to customize the item class used, via the `TListView.OnCreateItemClass` event, or by overriding `CreateListItem()` itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This leads to another problem, hence I extended the question